# Android app that uses a offline server database

Tags: android, database

I am a newbie to make android applications. I wanted to ask how i am going to do the following mentioned task.

Well i have a offline website that runs up on a server in my office. App would have a form whose `<select>` options are fetched from a database in our server.

Even if i make the form, how would i get all those options?

Even if i import the complete database in the android database, on fields update on server database, how would the fields update on the android app database?

Plus, how am i going to synchronize the inserted fields with the server database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could access it with a class like this.

package com.yourpackage

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;


      public class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
              String response = "";
              String DB_NAME = "sqlbeerlist.sqlite";

            try {
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
                int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

                // download the file
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/"+DB_NAME);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    //publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();

      } catch (IOException e) {
              Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e);
      }
              return response;
            }


      }
```

To execute the task use

```
String sUrl = "URL TO YOUR FILE";
    DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
            task.execute(new String[] { sUrl });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think  Android can't connect to a database server. You need to create a simple web service to pass the requests and return the response.

[This](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) shows how to setup a web service JSON (MySql+Php) + how to use it with Android.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Android CAN connect to database server directly using JDBC. I'm using FireBird database this way on a custom embedded application. However, i'd also recommend to create and use a webservice as you suggest.